# Is it possible to edit public google sheet in node.js using google sheet url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets

I want to edit google sheet in node.js.

But I have only google sheet url.
in this case it is possible to edit google sheet in node.js ?

Comment: yes, via the sheets api, the sheet id you will need is in the public html url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, if you have the right permissions, There is an api for this and even KIT : https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet